# Silently start Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I have an application that uses Crystal Reports to display information entered on various forms. This application is on various clients laptops ranging all over in performance specs. On some laptops, Crystal Reports can take 30+ seconds before it shows the first report, then after that they generally open quicker.

How do I pre-start Crystal Reports when my application starts so load time of the initial report is quicker? The way I'm considering doing it now is open up an empty report minimized at start, then timing it to close.

Comment: Thanks Otiel, for doing am unneeded edit including the removal of "Thanks, Dave K." and then removing my previous comment, all for the purpose of what, just trying to get another medal next to your name? How about next time you contribute and be helpful.

Comment: First, I don't consider it an "unneeded edit". See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts. Secondly, your previous comment (I assume you are talking about "using C#, WinForms, VS2010") was also *trashing* your question because it already appears in the tags, and that's what tags are for. I only edited your question to make it better, and this is how it works on SO. You should accept it and see the nice side of the feature. But if you're not happy with my edit, feel free to roll it back, it's your right I won't be offended :)

Comment: And btw, I don't care about medals (called badges here) next to my name. I'm pretty sure this edit won't get me really further to win another badge (well maybe in another [200 edits or so](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/223/copy-editor)). As for the "How about next time you contribute and be helpful", just know that I am the one who upvoted & favorited your question because I encounter the same problem. Now have a nice day ;)

Comment: ok, well THANK YOU for the explanation, but that will not make me remove the politeness of a "thanks" in any future post. I see how the greeting at the start has a valid argument, it is unneeded and does subtract from what is displayed on the main page to preview a post. A thank you (or some variation of it) will remain as I am thankful for any help I recieve for a question I post. So, with that said, Thanks for your input Otiel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loading CR on a separate thread when the app is starting up worked for me.

```
        //preload crystal reports on a seperate thread
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    using (ReportDocument preloadCrystalReport = new ReportDocument())
                    {
                        preloadCrystalReport.Load(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Reports/Report.rpt"));
                        PrintPreview preloadCrystalGUI = new PrintPreview().Init(preloadCrystalReport);
                        preloadCrystalGUI.Dispose();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    \\log exception
                }

            }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

The PrintPreview class in my case is a dialog with the CR control embedded in it.  I don't display the dialog when preloading.

I found that preloading the .rpt file also helped with the user experience

Comment: didn't use exactly what you gave me, but thanks for the input!